# Stuck trying to get NVIDIA binary drivers 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, ubuntu-drivers

I am investigating updating to an NVIDIA binary driver for a GTX 860M card on Ubuntu 14.04 running KDE. I am following the directions at [NVIDIA Binary Drivers HOWTO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia) but my system is not cooperating with the directions there. First off, the "Additional Drivers" UI does not show any restricted drivers available.  But if I try to troubleshoot to see what drivers are in use through the CLI with `ubuntu-drivers devices` command, the command does not output anything. Specifically,  when I run `ubuntu-drivers devices` I would expect something like this:

```
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
modalias : pci:something here
model    : GTX 806M or something like that
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
driver   : whatever binary drivers nvidia has available here...
```

but instead what I get is:

```
root@hades:~# ubuntu-drivers devices
root@hades:~#
```

If I do a `ubuntu-devices debug` then I do get output from the command -- a page or two of data that I can not make any sense of, but does not include anything related to vga (although there is some wmi stuff in there).

I believe that I am running the nouveau driver as `xrandr --listproviders` shows

```
Provider 0: id: 0x6b cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 8 associated providers: 1 name:Intel
Provider 1: id: 0x3f cap: 0x4, Source Offload crtcs: 0 outputs: 0 associated providers: 1 name:nouveau
```

and `lspci | grep -i vga` shows

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev a1)
```

but I am not sure what drivers to use at this point.  Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

- chooks

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're experiencing is a bug. I don't know the specifics, but other people with Optimus and your particular video card experience similar issues. See here for instance: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/731416/-337-12-beta-gm107m-geforce-gtx-860m-ee-no-devices-detected-/

Seeing as lspci sees your video card, I believe installing the proper driver will work. The nvidia 340 driver has been suggested to work with your setup, and can be installed from the xorg-edgers PPA on Ubuntu 14.04 with:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340`

Comment: Note that xorg-edgers is a *development* version and may stop working without notice - e.g. avoid updating as long as you have a working version: unless you're ready/capable to handle any kind of trouble by this fact.

Comment: Also note that the "nouveau" driver may be a problem when you attempt to use the proprietary drivers. You may well need to "Blacklist" it.

Comment: Good things to keep in mind.  My practice is to snapshot / and backup /boot before doing experiments like this, so I'll try to make sure my entire vacation isn't spent cursing X/Nvidia/Low-beer-supply :)